# Executing javascript file after ajax-loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How to can i run the script asd.js on data returned from ajax?

**HTML**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="asd.js"></script>
<div class="one">
    <ul id="qwe"></ul>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'abc.php',
                data: {cid: cid},

                success: function (data) {
                 $("#qwe").html(data);
                }
            });

    });
});
```

The data returned from success ajax is:

```html
<li> <a href="images3.jpg"><img src="images/a4.jpg"/>
         <span>
          <div class="title"><img src="Images/a5.jpg"/></div>
         </span>
      </a>
</li>
```

Comment: What script is that? If it's jQuery based, you should look into using the `.on()` method.

Comment: yes, the script based on jQuery.
i try to use in .on() but is still not working.

Comment: where is asd.js? Is it some other file not mentioned in this question?

Answer (score 0):

I assume asd.js adds some event hooks or something that you need to apply again to the HTML elements have come back from your AJAX call. So--wrap the contents of asd.js in a function, call that function once at the end of asd.js, then call that function again after you set $('#qwe').html(data).

If you are adding event hooks or working with the DOM in some other way, the initialization functions in asd.js should be called from the $(document).ready(...) function (otherwise you have potential race conditions going on here.)

If you can't alter asd.js, then things are going to be tougher. Work out which functions are important and call them. In the worst case scenario you could try dynamically removing and adding the script tag to cause it to re-run (but that's horrible).

Edit: ok, I wanted to illustrate this more clearly. I had assumed asd.js was simply a list of operations that executed immediately upon loading the script, e.g.

```
// asd.js: wiring up a bunch of events 
document.getElementById('...').onclick = function() { doSomething(); };
```

If that was the case, you would wrap it in a function like this:

```
// asd.js: wiring up a bunch of events 
function init()
{
  document.getElementById('...').onclick = function() { doSomething(); };
}

init();
```

Then also call init() from your response handler:

```
success: function (data) {
           $("#qwe").html(data);
           init();
         }
```

From your comments it seems that asd.js might look more like this:

```
// asd.js: wiring up a bunch of events 
jQuery(function() {
  document.getElementById('...').onclick = function() { doSomething(); };
});
```

If this is the case, you would do something like this:

```
// asd.js: wiring up a bunch of events 
jQuery(function() { init(); });

function init()
{
  document.getElementById('...').onclick = function() { doSomething(); };
}
```

The jQuery line can be shortened:

```
jQuery(init);
```

Comment: i warp all the script in a function, and i call it from the ajax, but the page is stuck he can't reloaded.
on console log it's write "jQuery is not defined."

Comment: Sorry, without knowing more about the precise arrangement of scripts it's hard to comment further. It sounds like this js file has a jQuery(function() {...}) that hooks document load. I would extract the contents of function to make function init(), then replace the jQuery(function { blah blah blah }) with jQuery(function { init(); }); or just jQuery(init), and call init() from your Ajax response event.

Comment: I added it ,and nothing happened it's as the beginning.

Comment: The principle here is pretty sound, so I would just reduce asd.js down to a single function and start adding the functionality back in function-by-function until you hit the problem, or use Firebug or similar to find the call stack associated with the error and trace it that way.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but i cant to do edit.

*** this is what asd.js cotain (if is help): ***

```
var yoxviewPath = getYoxviewPath();
var cssLink = top.document.createElement("link");
cssLink.setAttribute("rel", "Stylesheet");
cssLink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
cssLink.setAttribute("href", yoxviewPath + "yoxview.css");
top.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssLink);

function LoadScript(url)
{
    document.write( '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="' + url + '"><\/scr' + 'ipt>' ) ;
}

var jQueryIsLoaded = typeof jQuery != "undefined";

if (!jQueryIsLoaded)
    LoadScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");

LoadScript(yoxviewPath + "jquery.yoxview-2.2.min.js");

function getYoxviewPath()
{
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    var regex = /(.*\/)yoxview-init/i;
    for(var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++)
    {
        var currentScriptSrc = scripts[i].src;
        if (currentScriptSrc.match(regex))
            return currentScriptSrc.match(regex)[1];
    }

    return null;
}
// Remove the next line's comment to apply yoxview without knowing jQuery to all containers with class 'yoxview':
LoadScript(yoxviewPath + "yoxview-nojquery.js");
```